# delay(time); vs if(millis()-previous>time); and drift

Tags: arduino-due, code-review, timing

Going through an old project, I had code on two Arduino Due that looked like this

```
void loop()
{
  foo();
  delay(time);
}
```

taking to heart [the majority](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/AvoidDelay) of [literature](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/arduino-delay-function-shouldnt-use/) on using `delay();` I recoded this as

```
void loop()
{
  static unsigned long PrevTime;
  if(millis()-PrevTime>time)
  {
    foo();
    PrevTime=millis();
  }
}
```

However, this seems to have created a situation where the two devices drift over a period of time when they didn't previously

My question is twofold:

1. Why would `if(millis()-PrevTime>time)` cause more drift than
       `delay(time)`?
2. Is there a way to prevent this drift without going back to `delay(time)`?

Comment: What is the order of magnitude of "period of time" over which you notice the drift? Are the two devices in the same location, thus at the same temperature? Are they run on a crystal oscillator or a ceramic resonator?

Comment: Personally I prefer Majenko's solution, and always use it (I put the incrementing before the other instructions, but this is just a preference). Note, however, that this timing is PRECISELY 100ms, while the other code (`foo; delay;`) has a period longer than 100ms (it is 100ms + time of `foo`). So you will experience drift (but it is the `delay`-implemented SW which is drifting). In any case, keep in mind that even perfectly equal implementations "drift", because clocks are not equal; if you need complete synchronization use a signal to, well, synchronize the two programs.

Comment: The two devices are next to each other, after running from Friday at 17:00 to Monday at 9:00 there was a 4 min drift.

I'm deciding that I'm going to use a digital pin to synchronize the inputs as per your suggestion

Comment: "The two devices are next to each other, ..." that doesn't mean the timing mechanism is not accurate you are talking about an error rate of ~800ppm, high for two crystal oscillators but reasonable for even one ceramic resonator. you have to compare it vs. a reasonably accurate timing standard to be sure: crystals are typically within 20ppm, and tcxo's can do sub 1ppm. that would be my way of doing it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's one important thing that you need to remember when working with time on an Arudino of any form:

- Every operation takes time.

Your foo() function will take an amount of time. What that time is, we cannot say.

The most reliable way of dealing with time is to only rely on the time for triggering, not for working out when the next triggering should be.

For instance, take the following:

```
if (millis() - last > interval) {
    doSomething();
    last = millis();
}
```

The variable `last` will be the time the routine triggered *plus the time `doSomething` took to run. So say `interval` is 100, and `doSomething` takes 10ms to run, you will get triggerings at 101ms, 212ms, 323ms, etc. Not the 100ms you were expecting.

So one thing you can do is to always use the same time regardless by remembering it at once specific point (as Juraj suggests):

```
uint32_t time = millis();

if (time - last > interval) {
    doSomething();
    last = time;
}
```

Now the time that `doSomething()` takes will have no effect on anything. So you will get triggerings at 101ms, 202ms, 303ms, etc. Still not quite the 100ms you wanted - because you're looking for *more* that 100ms having passed - and that means 101ms or more.  Instead you should use `>=`:

```
uint32_t time = millis();

if (time - last >= interval) {
    doSomething();
    last = time;
}
```

Now, assuming that nothing else happens in your loop you get triggerings at 100ms, 200ms, 300ms, etc.  But note that bit: *"as long as nothing else happens in your loop"*...

What happens if an operation that takes 5ms happens to occur at 99ms...? Your next triggering will be delayed until 104ms. That's a drift. But it's easy to combat. Instead of saying "The recorded time is now" you say "The recorded time is 100ms later than it was". That means that no matter what delays you get in your code your triggering will always be at 100ms intervals, or drift within a 100ms tick.

```
if (millis() - last >= interval) {
    doSomething();
    last += interval;
}
```

Now you will get triggerings at 100ms, 200ms, 300ms, etc. Or if there are delays in other bits of code you may get 100ms, 204ms, 300ms, 408ms, 503ms, 600ms, etc.  It always tries to run it as close to the interval as possible regardless of delays.  And if you have delays that are greater than the interval it will automatically run your routine enough times to catch up with the current time.

Before you had *drift*. Now you have *jitter*.

Answer (score 1):

Because you reset the timer after the operation.

```
static unsigned long PrevTime=millis();

unsigned long t = millis();

if (t - PrevTime > time) {
    foo();
    PrevTime = t;
}
```

Comment: no. notice that PrevTime is static.

Comment: @dannyf, yes, and?

Comment: if you knew what "static" means, you would know why your answer isn't correct.

Comment: I know what static does with local variable.. I do not understand why you think my answer has something to do with the static. I just moved the current millis reading before foo() is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

For what you are trying to do, delay() is the appropriate way to implement the code. The reason you would want to use the if(millis()) is if you want to allow the main loop to continue to loop so your code or some other code outside of that loop can do other processing.

For example:

```
long next_trigger_time = 0L;
long interval = DESIRED_INTERVAL;

void loop() {
   do_something(); // check a sensor or value set by an interrupt
   long m = millis();
   if (m >= next_trigger_time) {
       next_trigger_time = m + interval;
       foo();
   }
}
```

This would run foo() on the specified interval while allowing the loop to continue to run in between. I put the calculation of next_trigger_time before the call to foo() to help minimize the drift, but it is inevitable. If drift is a significant concern, use an interrupt timer or some sort of clock/timer synchronization. Also remember that millis() will wrap around after some period of time and I didn't account for that to keep the code example simple.

Comment: Hate to mention this: rollover problem in 52 days.

Comment: I already mentioned the rollover issue at the end of my answer.

Comment: Well, solve it.

Comment: My standard consulting fee $100/hr if you want me to write code for you. I think what I have written is a sufficiently relevant.

Comment: Are you aware that Majenko posted a more complete and better answer that yours? Are you aware that your code doens't compile? That `long m - millis()` doesn't do what you intend to do? That's on the house.

Comment: Then vote for his answer if you like it better.

Comment: I fail to see the point in posting a deficient solution when a good one has already been accepted. Majenko's solution doesn't suffer from the rollover problem, and it shows that the drift is not “inevitable”, but rather very easy to avoid. This answer provides no added value.

Comment: @EdgarBonet, Majenko's solution doesn't discuss why you might choose to not use delay() even if it does cause drift. My code example was meant to highlight that, not provide a "complete" solution. So my answer does add value to the discussion, but I guess you didn't actually read my answer either.